# Android Database not being created on install / android packages

Tags: android, database, android-emulator, android-contentprovider

I want to use a SQLite database within my application. I have created a class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. When I first wrote the code the database appeared in `/data/data/(package)/database. The package name was my reverse domain + /mobile/app`. I then created a separate package within my project reverse `domain + /mobile/data` and moved my Database class into it.

`/data/data/(original package)/database` existed until I reloaded(to not use the snapshot) my emulator.

since then:

`/data/data/(original package)/` is created but with no database directory, `/data/data/(data package)/` is not created on the file system. I have tried:

moving my database class back to the original package

creating a new version of the emulator

uninstalling the app within the emulator and then re-installing it.

increasing the database version variable

commenting our code associated with the database class in other parts of my app.

Here is my db class code.

```
public class BusinessOpsDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String TAG = "BusinessOpsDatabase";
private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DB_NAME = "bss_business_ops";

// country table variables
public static final String TABLE_COUNTRY = "country";
public static final String ID = "_ID";
public static final String COL_COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRY = "create table "
        + TABLE_COUNTRY + " (" + ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COL_COUNTRY_NAME
        + " text not null);";
private static final String COUNTRY_SCHEMA = CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRY;


public BusinessOpsDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // create tables
    db.execSQL(COUNTRY_SCHEMA);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // drop country
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database. Existing contents will be lost. ["
            + oldVersion + "]->[" + newVersion + "]");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COUNTRY);


    // create tables
    onCreate(db);

}
}
```

Comment: have any exception occured?

Comment: not as far as I can tell, nothing fatal.

Comment: I am using 'adb logcat BusinessOpsDatabase:V *:S' at the terminal and added Log.d(TAG, "OnCreate") to my onCreate method. I don't think onCreate() is being called.

Comment: check your DB helper calling method

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the problem by adding the following code to the database constructor.

```
SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_SQLite_Database_Tutorial

Use above link to learn . you may solve all your problems regarding sqlite